# Google Maps Marker doesn't show up in my website

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me please I don't understand javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 16,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(31.6321288,-8.0099319,787),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(31.6321288,-8.0099319,787);
        var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            icon: "We Are Here"
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=My-API-Here&callback=initMap"></script> I added my API key but still doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Google Documentation, it is as follows.
Make sure you include this line in your html tag and get your [Google Map API Key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key) to replace the `YOUR_API_KEY`

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple markers</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

      function initMap() {
        var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: myLatLng
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          title: 'Hello World!'
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Didn't work, I've tried it. <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=My-API-Here&callback=initMap"></script>

Comment: Hi I have tested on my local machine, it works fine. 1. you got to obtain the api key from Google Map API Key from https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_backend,geocoding_backend,directions_backend,distance_matrix_backend,elevation_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE&reusekey=true. 2. Then run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in the root directory of your html file to start http server and navigate to localhost:8000 to check the html. If it doesn't work still, please copy and paste the javascript console error

Answer (score 0):

1 - You need to create a Google Maps project and generate an API KEY (https://console.developers.google.com). It's very simple and fast.

2 - So, you need to import GoogleMapsAPI, changing YOUR_API_KEY for your API KEY:

```
<script async defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

---

The result is something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Simple markers</title>
        <style>
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            #map {
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script>
            function initMap() {
                var myLatLng = {lat:31.6321288, lng:-8.0099319};

                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    zoom: 16,
                    center: myLatLng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                });

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatLng,
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Hello World!'
                });
            }
        </script>
        <script async defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Didn't work, I've tried it. <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=My-API-Here&callback=initMap"></script>